# how to use the input of confirm box in C#

Tags: c#, javascript

Here i have used javascript to ask whether to replace the file or not in javascript... now how can i use that input in c# code to replace the file or cancel it.

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>confirm('FiileAlready existing Rplace it?')</script>");
Response.Flush();
```

i should convey the output to c# as whether it is Yes or no From the javscript

Answer (score 0):

You can not convey the output of confirmation in codebehind. One way is make ajax request after confirmation so you can make changes in codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have taken means the response is discarded.

Apart from needing to capture the response in a JavaScript variable, you will then need to convey it to C# - there are multiple ways to do so (form with hidden input that is auto submitted, change to the URL, using AJAX to call a web method and more).

In essence, you need to write some more JavaScript to support whichever method you select in order to transfer the data to the server side.